# Calling current url with window.location.href on tableau server

Tags: javascript, tableau-api

i have created a plain html test.html  which includes my js script. For an example

```
<html>
..
<script>
console.log(windows.location.href)
</script>
..
..
</html>
```

Then ill upload this on my webserver on siteground, my domain on my siteground is [www.farid.com](http://www.farid.com) , to access this file . on my url i will include
[www.farid.com/helloworld.html](http://www.farid.com/helloworld.html)

inside my inspect element , windows.location.href will print ( " [www.farid.com/helloworld.html](http://www.farid.com/helloworld.html) " )

Now, on tableau server, i am creating a js extension.
my tableau server is as shown below , it starts with https://laptop....
[image]

Its like adding a container(plugin) where it will then include your custom js/html page , "my first javascript" is where it will load test.html.

[image: ![enter image description here]

The objective to try to print the main url which is showing on my browser with  as https://laptop-739.... instead of test.html . Is this possible to somehow force javascript to read the main url which is not test.html

[image]

Comment: could you please reword your question? it is unclear what you are asking.  "my objective is to call https://dev.test.com" instead of www.test.com/helloworld.html on my console.log ." ????

Comment: Hi @PA. , i have revised my question. Thank you for highlighting

Comment: Sorry, I still can't understand your question. What exactly do you want to achieve? You say you want to "call" on browser laptop-739iu an "inside url"? Sorry, it does not make any sense to me.

Comment: hi @PA. , i have revised the whole question.

Comment: is it included as an iframe? try to print both  `window.location` and `window.parent.location`

Comment: @PA. , i have already came out with the solution, i did a window.deferrer and this was able to capture the url . However, i will try the approach on window.parent.location. Thanks